# Pygame obstacles not being generated more than once

Tags: python, pygame

So right now I am learning pygame and I'm using sentdex's tutorials. On I believe his 6th pygame tutorial he showed us how to generate more than just one block. I added the code, but it didin't work. I don't understand why it didn't work? Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? 
Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

window_width = 800
window_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width,window_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('MyFirstGame')

carImg = pygame.image.load("racecar.png")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def blocks(block_x, block_y, block_width, block_height, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [block_x, block_y, block_width, block_height])


def crash():
    print("YOUR GARBAGE! Press C to play again or Q to quit.")
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit
                quit()
                gameExit = True                
            if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                gameLoop()
                print("User has decided to play again")


def gameLoop():
    # Defining variables to draw and move car        
    car_x = 350
    car_y = 400
    car_x_change = 0

    car_w = 100
    car_h = 100

    # Defining variables to draw blocks

    block_x = random.randrange(0, window_width)
    block_y = -600
    block_speed = 7
    block_width = 100
    block_height = 100

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    car_x_change += -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    car_x_change += 5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        car_x += car_x_change
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        # blocks((block_x,block_y,[block_width,block_height,black))
        blocks(block_x, block_y, block_width, block_height, black)
        block_y += block_speed

        gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (car_x,car_y))

        if car_x >= window_width:
                gameExit = True
                crash()
        if car_x <= 0:
                gameExit = True
                crash()
        if car_y > window_height:
            block_y = 0 - block_height
            block_x = random.randrange(0,window_width-block_width)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)


gameLoop()
pygame.quit
quit()
```

Comment: Also I believe the crash function doesn't work either, don't worry about that though. Thanks :)

Comment: This is not a minimal example. Also you didn't say anything what is the specific problem.

Comment: you have only one pair `block_x, block_y` so don't expect that you get more than one block. You can create list with many pairs `x,y` and use `for` loop to draw them as block. You will need `for` loop also to check collision with  car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pair `block_x, block_y` can't be use to draw many blocks.

You have to create list with pairs `(x,y)` for all blocks which you want to draw. You have to use `for` loops to create blocks (pairs `(x,y)`), to move them, and to draw them.

BTW: running `gameloop()` inside `crash()` create recursion which is not prefered method.

My version with more information in comments `# changed`

```
import pygame
import random

# changed: better organized code

# --- constants --- (UPPERCASE_NAMES)

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600

# --- functions --- (lowercase_names)

def blocks(points, width, height, color):
    # changed: use `for` to draw all blocks
    for x, y in points:
        pygame.draw.rect(display, color, [x, y, width, height])

def crash():
    print("YOUR GARBAGE! Press C to play again or Q to quit.")

    # changed: return `True/False` insted of executing gameloop() 
    # because it was not good idea

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    return True # True = quit
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    print("User has decided to play again")
                    return False # false = continue

def gameloop():

    # --- objects ---

    car_image = pygame.image.load("racecar.png")

    # Defining variables to draw and move car        
    car_x = 350
    car_y = 400
    car_x_change = 0

    car_w = 100
    car_h = 100

    # BTW: you could use `pygame.Rect` to keep position and size 
    # car_rect = car_image.get_rect(x=350, y=450)

    # Defining variables to draw blocks

    block_speed = 7
    block_width = 100
    block_height = 100

    # changed: create list with points x,y

    pairs = []
    for _ in range(10):
        x = random.randrange(0, WINDOW_WIDTH)
        y = -block_height
        pairs.append( (x, y) )

    # --- mainloop ---

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        # --- events ---

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    car_x_change -= 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    car_x_change += 5
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    car_x_change += 5 # changed: wrong variable, use +=
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    car_x_change -= 5 # changed: wrong variable, use -=

        # --- updates ---

        # changed: all moves before draws

        # move car              
        car_x += car_x_change

        # changed: one `if` for both crashes (`car_x`)

        if car_x < 0 or car_x >= WINDOW_WIDTH:
                # changed: use value from crash to set gameExit 
                # and to move car to start position
                gameExit = crash()
                if not gameExit:
                    car_x = 350
                    car_y = 400

        # changed: use `for` to move all points 
        # and to check if they need new random place
        # move blocks
        moved_pairs = []
        for x, y in pairs:
            y += block_speed
            if y > WINDOW_HEIGHT:
                 y = -block_height
                 x = random.randrange(0, WINDOW_WIDTH - block_width)     
            moved_pairs.append( (x, y) )
        pairs = moved_pairs

        # --- draws ---

        # changed: all draws after moves

        display.fill(WHITE)

        blocks(pairs, block_width, block_height, BLACK)

        display.blit(car_image, (car_x, car_y))

        pygame.display.update()

        # --- FPS ---

        clock.tick(30)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('MyFirstGame')

gameloop()

pygame.quit() # changed: forgot ()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks for not just posting the changed code but explaining it with comments and more :) I didn't understand the code underneath this comment though  # changed: create list with points x,y. What is .append? And why is there no value in pairs[ ]?